# How do I create a filter to identify any plus addressed email?

Tags: regex, email, gmail

I use *"plus addressing"* in gmail often.

It is difficult at times, as the web interface does not default to showing much of the headers aside from a usually truncated From: and To: often displayed as "me".  "me" does little good to *"at a glance"* see if it is a *plus addressed* email or not.

I am getting false positives in my spam folder, some are *plus addressed* in format.  So me+possibleScamSite@gmail.com can end up in the spam folder/tag.

I want to create a filter that matches on the plus, and tell it to never send it to spam.  It should be rare that a *plus addressed* message is spam.  At least in theory — I won't know until I test it which I can't do until I figure out the syntax.

So far, I have tried a few regex's. but they grab more than I want.  I actually can't even seem to find a way to search for any emails To:me+plus-addressed-email-address@gmail.com

```
.+\+.+\@gmail.com
```

is as close as I can come but it doesn't work correct, or in a way I can even estimate what gmail is doing. My thought *( on the above regex )* was wildcard (repeating), literal "+" symbol (escaped), wildcard (repeating).  But I may be messing up my regex and the first wildcard is being *greedy* and matching any string.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify start-of-string/end-of-string anchors, the regex should match anywhere within the string.  So it should be sufficient to write:

```
\+
```

You're right that your `.+` will match everything, and leave you with nothing to match against your `\+`, for example.  You can avoid this by explicitly excluding the terminating symbol from the characters to repeat:

```
[^+]+\+[^@]+@gmail\.com
```

where `[^x]` means ‘any character but `x`’.

Comment: Using http://regexpal.com I put in me@gmail.com
me+test@gmail.com
me+someone@gmail.com
me+amazon.com@gmail.com
me+foobar.baz@gmail.com and used [^+]+\+[^@]+@gmail\.com which yileded zero matches. Searching on that regex in gmail found 0 plus addressed emails.  I don't even know that gmail supports regex, but they do support + addressing, so they should have a way of searching on a non specific + address, as no one can remember all the variations one has made.  That would be like a url shortener not letting you get to your short-url in your account after it has been made.

Comment: regexpal.com correctly matches all those test cases for me.  Are you sure you pasted the expression in correctly?

GMail does not support regular expressions that I can see, but you should still be able to search `to:+`.

Comment: There's a good chance I messed up. Regardless, as far as I can tell, there is no regex support in gmail. I thought I had it with just doing a search in gmail for "user+" which should return all plus addressed email addresses. I tried To:user+ as well, plus different quoting options. Nothing works, it either returns all emails, or none. Even a search just for "+" does nothing useful. Plus addressing is nice, but I never take the time to add filters, and figure when I see them I will act on them at that time, but now I have no way of finding them unless I remember exactly all the ones I used.

Comment: How about: `-to:you@gmail.com` (or perhaps `to:-you@gmail.com`)?